# Where can I find complete list of devstack services?

Tags: openstack, devstack, openstack-neutron

In devstack local.conf, we can enable or disable services as follows :

```
disable_service n-net
enable_service q-svc
```

But where can I find the complete list of services for all modules, Cielometer, Heat, etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

devstack have screens for that, you need to `./rejoin-stack.sh` and then `ctrl + a +` and number of the service that you see on screen, you can also navigate `ctrl + a + p` for previous and `ctrl + a + n` for next. If you want to detach screen hit `ctrl + a + d`

Comment: Note: This will show list of installed services only.

Answer (score 0):

Check devtsack source

[Link1](https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack/search?p=2&q=enable_service&utf8=%E2%9C%93)
   [Link2](https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=disable_service&type=Code)

These are the services.

postgresql
 
s-proxy 
s-object 
s-container 
s-account
 n-net
 q-svc
 q-agt
 q-dhcp
 q-meta
 q-l3
 tempest
 ceilometer-acompute ceilometer-acentral ceilometer-anotification ceilometer-collector ceilometer-api
 ceilometer-alarm-notifier ceilometer-alarm-evaluator
 zaqar-server
 s-proxy s-object s-container s-account
 n-net
 q-svc q-agt q-dhcp q-l3
 qpid
 s-proxy s-object s-container s-account
 postgresql
 ldap

Answer (score 0):

You cay run this to search the "flags" again the `stack.sh`:

```
grep "if is_service_enabled" stack.sh
```

Output looks like this:

```
if is_service_enabled nova; then
if is_service_enabled g-reg; then
...
```

And, if you use a text editor to open `stack.sh` and search for `if is_service_enabled`, you will see detail description of each flag.